# error message using if statement doesn't work (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

The error messages should be displayed in the span elements to the right of the text boxes, and the error messages should be:

"Must be a positive number less than $10,000"

"Must be a positive number less than 12"

But my code only displays "Must be a positive number less than $10,000" which is subtotal_message.

How can I make both messages show up when its condition is not satisfied?

```
 if (isNaN(subtotal) || subtotal <= 0 || subtotal > 10000) {
          $("subtotal_message").innerHTML = "Must be a positive number less than $10,000"; 
      } 

 else if (isNaN(taxRate) || taxRate <= 0 || taxRate > 12) {
          $("tax_rate_message").innerHTML = "Must be a positve number less than 12";
      } 

 else { var salesTax = calculate_salesTax(subtotal, taxRate);
          $("sales_tax").value = calculate_salesTax(subtotal, taxRate);
          $("total").value = (parseFloat($("subtotal").value) + parseFloat(salesTax)).toFixed(2);
      }
```

HTML within body tag

```
    <div id="taxCalc">
    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" >
    <span id="subtotal_message" class="subtotal_message">Enter order subtotal</span><br />

    <label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tax_rate" >
    <span id="tax_rate_message" class="tax_rate_message">Enter sales tax rate (99.9)</span><br />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `else if` here.
If one of the `if` conditions execute, the others won't execute.
I suggest you remove `else if` and replace it with `if`.

Comment: can I use two if statements at once?

Comment: Of course you can use them. You can even nest if statements inside each other